# sklearn's KFold function with shuffle and random_state

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-fold

I'm trying to understand how to use the cross-validation function [`sklearn.model_selection.KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html). If I define (like in this [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/corochann/optuna-tutorial-for-hyperparameter-optimization))

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False, random_state=100)
```

I get

```
ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False.
You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
```

What does this error mean and why is it necessary to set `random_state=None` or `shuffle=True`?

Answer (score 5):

Shuffling in this context means that the data is first randomly shuffled before splitting into test/train. The `random_state` will allow the way in which the data is shuffled to be repeatable. Without the shuffling switched on, the `random_state` has no meaning.

Comment: Thanks, what references do you recommend for learning more on data preprocessing? I don't find the sklearn docs that helpful.

Comment: That's the correct answer indeed, although I confess I am puzzled why the sklearn designers decided to throw an error in this case; arguably a warning would be more than enough.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me.                                                                                        
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=10, shuffle=True)

Answer (score 4):

[By default in kfold `shuffle=False`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html), by putting `random_state` to value, you need to activate `shuffle`, `shuffle=True`, which will work.

Example:

```python
k_fold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True, random_state=10)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).